# Using results from one sql query to get results from another - where to put moveNext

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to use the results from the first SQL query to populate a variable used in the second query but always seem to get the wrong results from the second query.

The first query is:

```
$povi_query = " SELECT products_options_values_id
                FROM orders_products_attributes
                WHERE orders_id = $ord_id";
$povi_result = $db->Execute($povi_query);
```

The results from this are 50, 40, 40, 34, 12 and are correct when compared to the data in the db

The second query is:

```
$sku_query = "SELECT  pas.sku, 
                      pas.products_attributes_ids, 
                      pa.products_attributes_id, 
                      pa.options_values_id, 
                      opa.products_options_values_id
              FROM  products_attributes_skus pas
                JOIN products_attributes pa
                  ON pas.products_attributes_ids = pa.products_attributes_id
                JOIN orders_products_attributes opa
                  ON pa.options_values_id = opa.products_options_values_id
              WHERE pas.products_id = $prod_id
                AND opa.orders_id = $ord_id
                AND opa.products_options_values_id = $povi";
$sku_result = $db->Execute($sku_query);
```

If I run this query in phpMyAdmin, substituting $povi with the answers from the first query I get the correct result each time, but when I run them together the data is all wrong.

The code as it is in the actual file is laid out as:

```
// Begin SKU modification 2 of 3
$ord_id = $orderitems_result->fields['orders_id'];
$prod_id = $orderitems_result->fields['products_id'];   
$sku = '';  
$povi_query = " SELECT products_options_values_id
                FROM orders_products_attributes
                WHERE orders_id = $ord_id";
$povi_result = $db->Execute($povi_query);
while (!$povi_result->EOF){
  $povi = $povi_result->fields['products_options_values_id']; 

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($povi);
  echo '</pre>';

  $sku_query = "SELECT  pas.sku, 
                        pas.products_attributes_ids, 
                        pa.products_attributes_id, 
                        pa.options_values_id, 
                        opa.products_options_values_id
                FROM  products_attributes_skus pas
                  JOIN products_attributes pa
                    ON pas.products_attributes_ids = pa.products_attributes_id
                  JOIN orders_products_attributes opa
                    ON pa.options_values_id = opa.products_options_values_id
                WHERE pas.products_id = $prod_id
                  AND opa.orders_id = $ord_id
                  AND opa.products_options_values_id = $povi";
  $sku_result = $db->Execute($sku_query);

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($sku);
  echo '</pre>';

  $povi_result->MoveNext();
}
```

I have tried changing the while and MoveNext positions, adding one to the second query too, but all that achieved was the first result from query1 and a never ending list of the first result from query2 or more output similar to that where I had to force the process to end.

I should add that it MUST take the first result of 50 and then run through the second query, then take the second result of 40 and run through the second query again. If it takes an array of 50 40 40 34 12 then the second query will give incorrect results as it is doing now because 34 would also return data matching pas.products_id = $prod_id and opa.orders_id = $ord_id because that product has multiple sku's depending on pack size.

Any suggestions at all?
If you need further information to help, then please ask.

Thanks

Comment: Do not use comma join syntax. See proper JOIN syntax instead. All of the above can (and should) be accomplished within a single query.

Comment: Agreed, I made an edit changing it from comma join syntax to proper JOIN syntax.

Comment: @Strawberry SQL is not my strong point. Joins always confuse the hell out of me and I've never been successful in my attempts. I thought that you can only use a join when you have the same field names in multiple tables.

Comment: @StevePrice No, the field names need not match, only the values.

Comment: @MichaelL. I see what you have done with the joins, but i'm still non the wiser how I join in a third table so that the results are achieved with a single query. I did try doing joins on this last night but ended up in a right mess which is why I reverted to the original code

Comment: What happens if you omit the first query altogether and also omit the `AND opa.products_options_values_id = $povi` condition?   The `AND opa.orders_id = $ord_id` condition duplicates the logic of the first query.

Comment: @MichaelL. I get incorrect data, starting with sku LSA06 which is what I get as the second result when it was using original code and running the secondary query using 50, 40, 40, 34, 12 as the result from the first query

Comment: Would it help if I gave you the relevant table layout and sample data for this order?

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful.  The easiest thing would be to setup a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: @MichaelL. SQL fiddle here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f05d/2 Note, product_id and products_options_values_id should tie up as follows: 370/50, 378/40, 374/40, 532/34, 1/12

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing both queries with this query:

```
$sku_query = "SELECT  pas.sku, 
                      pas.products_attributes_ids, 
                      pa.products_attributes_id, 
                      pa.options_values_id, 
                      opa.products_options_values_id,
                      pas.products_id
              FROM  products_attributes_skus pas
                JOIN products_attributes pa
                  ON pas.products_attributes_ids = pa.products_attributes_id
                JOIN orders_products_attributes opa
                  ON pa.options_values_id = opa.products_options_values_id
              WHERE opa.orders_id = $ord_id
              GROUP BY  pas.sku, 
                        pas.products_attributes_ids, 
                        pa.products_attributes_id, 
                        pa.options_values_id, 
                        opa.products_options_values_id,
                        pas.products_id";
```

The GROUP BY is necessary because some values for `products_options_values_id` appear multiple times in the `products_options_values_id` table and it was producing duplicate rows.  Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f05d/23) for my query.

Comment: Whilst it work beautifully on the fiddle using the limited data I could fit into 8000 characters, in the realworld situation of a full blown product database it returns completely unexpected results. If there is any way I can PM you I can give you access to a full database to see what it does.